# Is my poor wireless connection the result of a bad driver?

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.04, kubuntu

I've just installed Kubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo T560 Thinkpad.  The wireless connection works poorly - on startup, it won't search for wireless networks (there's also no UI element available to prompt a search for networks, but that's a different complaint).  And when a wireless network is found, it routinely drops the connection.

Basically, I have to keep a terminal open to run `$ sudo service network-manager restart` almost constantly.  None of the other devices that use the network have a similar problem.

Is this likely a driver issue?  The wireless device is

```
product: Wireless 8260
vendor: Intel Corporation
```

and I'm using the `iwlwifi` driver.

Edit: here's the output of `dmesg | grep iwl`:

`[    4.853206] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-19.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.853222] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-18.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.853231] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.853602] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[    4.864965] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.904463] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x208
[    4.904778] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.905880] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    5.050828] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    5.054589] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
[    5.399303] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    5.400038] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    5.540881] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    5.541309] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1668.562182] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1668.563595] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1668.702349] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1668.702959] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2082.791322] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2082.792716] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2082.931669] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2082.932277] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2986.102813] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2986.103733] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2986.241431] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2986.241948] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3183.242126] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3183.243588] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3183.381723] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3183.382147] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 4635.249047] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 4635.250403] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 4635.388702] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 4635.389223] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 7071.802648] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 7071.804023] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 7071.941558] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 7071.942093] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled`

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Done.  So what does error -2 mean?  That seems like the type of thing that a developer might document somewhere accessible by a search engine.  I guess that would just be silly, though.

Comment: It simply means that the system looked for the latest and, presumably best, firmware but didn't find it. It then tried the next newer, didn't find it either, and so on. I will propose a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you update the firmware files. With a working internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.159_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
```

Reboot. Is there any improvement?

If there is no improvement, I recommend that you try the steps outlined here: [Ubuntu 16.04 wifi Intel 7265 slow/disconnecting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804607/ubuntu-16-04-wifi-intel-7265-slow-disconnecting/804619#804619)

Comment: To clarify, @chili555 suggests downloading v. 1.159 of the linux-firmware package, which is not included in the 16.04 (Xenial) repo that has only up to 1.157.  This package includes the firmware files for my card, shown in the output of `dmesg | grep iwl` as the files iwlwifi-8000C-*.ucode.  The 1.157 firmware package of 16.04 includes only up to iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode, while Yakkety's [1.159 package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/1.159) includes up to version -22.  The fact that 1.159 is not in the 16.04 repo is why we're circumventing APT to get it.

Comment: This did not work.  There was no apparent change in the wireless connection's behavior.  I'll now try following the link you provided.