# Ubuntu 16.04 wifi Intel 7265 slow/disconnecting

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04, intel

Hey I have a new Asus Zenbook with Intel 7265 wifi card and constantly in couple of minutes internet connection is getting very slow/not working at all. I have newest driver from Intel site lwifi. Does someone know what is not right? Here is message from dmesg:

```
               iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[   24.649401] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode failed with error -2
[   24.649592] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-20.ucode failed with error -2
[   24.649609] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
[   24.649619] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode failed with error -2
[   24.649788] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode failed with error -2
[   24.650872] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   24.655903] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   24.659008] EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
[   24.659696] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam (0bda:57cb)
[   24.662859] uvcvideo 1-5:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[   24.662864] uvcvideo 1-5:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[   24.662867] uvcvideo 1-5:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[   24.662988] input: USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input8
[   24.663058] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   24.663060] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   24.668056] pstore: Registered efi as persistent store backend
[   24.687262] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[   24.687605] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   24.688054] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   24.778942] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   24.819868] asus_wmi: ASUS WMI generic driver loaded
[   24.828909] asus_wmi: Initialization: 0x1
[   24.828946] asus_wmi: BIOS WMI version: 7.9
[   24.829000] asus_wmi: SFUN value: 0xa2077
[   24.836695] input: Asus WMI hotkeys as /devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/input/input9
[   24.843129] asus_wmi: Number of fans: 1
[   24.869013] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[   24.873609] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[   24.873612] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[   24.873614] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore
[   24.873616] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
[   24.912095] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: CX20751/2: BIOS auto-probing.
[   24.912481] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for CX20751/2: line_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[   24.912484] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   24.912486] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x16/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   24.912487] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   24.912488] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[   24.912490] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x1a
[   24.912492] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x19
[   24.913482] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: Enable sync_write for stable communication
[   24.929007] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input10
[   24.929075] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input11
[   24.929146] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input12
[   24.929201] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input13
[   24.929256] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
[   24.971387] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[   24.982016] i2c-ELAN0100:00 supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[   24.987196] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounting ext2 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[   24.990785] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   25.019284] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
[   25.094822] input: Elan Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-5/i2c-ELAN0100:00/input/input15
[   25.397480] Adding 8281596k swap on /dev/mapper/cryptswap1.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:8281596k SSFS
[   25.408978] audit: type=1400 audit(1469813913.829:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/bin/ubuntu-core-launcher" pid=2630 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   25.417142] audit: type=1400 audit(1469813913.837:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=2627 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   25.417150] audit: type=1400 audit(1469813913.837:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=2627 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   25.417154] audit: type=1400 audit(1469813913.837:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=2627 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   25.417158] audit: type=1400 audit(1469813913.837:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=2627 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   25.418612] audit: type=1400 audit(1469813913.841:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=2626 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   25.418618] audit: type=1400 audit(1469813913.841:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="chromium" pid=2626 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   25.420653] audit: type=1400 audit(1469813913.841:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=2632 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   25.423659] audit: type=1400 audit(1469813913.845:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="webbrowser-app" pid=2631 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   25.423664] audit: type=1400 audit(1469813913.845:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="oxide_helper" pid=2631 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   25.948089] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   25.948092] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   25.948095] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   26.557450] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[   26.557812] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   26.558419] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   26.619691] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   26.620140] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   26.641313] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[   26.798552] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[   27.540528] fuse init (API version 7.24)
[   29.064300] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   29.064306] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   29.064310] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   32.761088] wlp2s0: authenticate with 84:a4:23:61:56:30
[   32.773665] wlp2s0: send auth to 84:a4:23:61:56:30 (try 1/3)
[   32.776574] wlp2s0: authenticated
[   32.778051] wlp2s0: associate with 84:a4:23:61:56:30 (try 1/3)
[   32.781676] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 84:a4:23:61:56:30 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
[   32.782709] wlp2s0: associated
[   32.782740] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[  159.837155] wlp2s0: disconnect from AP 84:a4:23:61:56:30 for new auth to 84:a4:23:61:56:31
[  159.849137] wlp2s0: authenticate with 84:a4:23:61:56:31
[  159.855168] wlp2s0: send auth to 84:a4:23:61:56:31 (try 1/3)
[  159.958360] wlp2s0: send auth to 84:a4:23:61:56:31 (try 2/3)
[  159.985777] wlp2s0: authenticated
[  159.990344] wlp2s0: associate with 84:a4:23:61:56:31 (try 1/3)
[  159.996099] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 84:a4:23:61:56:31 (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=1)
[  159.998072] wlp2s0: associated
[  160.023837] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 84:a4:23:61:56:31
[  585.793573] wlp2s0: disconnect from AP 84:a4:23:61:56:31 for new auth to 84:a4:23:61:56:30
[  585.798922] wlp2s0: authenticate with 84:a4:23:61:56:30
[  585.811317] wlp2s0: send auth to 84:a4:23:61:56:30 (try 1/3)
[  585.814233] wlp2s0: authenticated
[  585.815870] wlp2s0: associate with 84:a4:23:61:56:30 (try 1/3)
[  585.819722] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 84:a4:23:61:56:30 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
[  585.821266] wlp2s0: associated
[  705.777594] wlp2s0: disconnect from AP 84:a4:23:61:56:30 for new auth to 84:a4:23:61:56:31
[  705.780721] wlp2s0: authenticate with 84:a4:23:61:56:31
[  705.782945] wlp2s0: send auth to 84:a4:23:61:56:31 (try 1/3)
[  705.886621] wlp2s0: send auth to 84:a4:23:61:56:31 (try 2/3)
[  705.914854] wlp2s0: authenticated
[  705.918596] wlp2s0: associate with 84:a4:23:61:56:31 (try 1/3)
[  705.926879] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 84:a4:23:61:56:31 (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=1)
[  705.929268] wlp2s0: associated
[  705.963554] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 84:a4:23:61:56:31
[  949.136944] wlp2s0: disconnect from AP 84:a4:23:61:56:31 for new auth to 84:a4:23:61:56:30
[  949.141177] wlp2s0: authenticate with 84:a4:23:61:56:30
[  949.146439] wlp2s0: send auth to 84:a4:23:61:56:30 (try 1/3)
[  949.149310] wlp2s0: authenticated
```

Comment: Is it a 5GHz connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I own and use successfully two Intel wireless devices. I have honed a few techniques in several years and thousands of forum posts.

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/...pv6-ignore.png This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

Finally, I suggest that you update the firmware.

```
cd /lib/firmware
sudo wget https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware/raw/master/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode
```

Reboot and tell us how it's working.

Comment: You are correct about `reg get`. The problem is that not all Ubuntu releases have correct `crda` information for some countries. If some channel is not listed, the connection is allowed on this intel adapter, but it is intermittent. For example 14.04 still does not have 5GHz channels for Russia. They never updated crda.

Comment: @Pilot6 Do you know of any place we can get the text to add? Can we edit regulatory.bin?

Comment: Yes we can. Let me remember how. But in most cases it is easier to download and install a package from a newer Ubuntu version, or Debian testing.

Comment: This perhaps? http://networkgeekstuff.com/networking/how-to-create-custom-linux-wi-fi-regulatory-database-to-unlock-30db1000mw/

Comment: Anyway we need to build a package. I did that a few times. But first it makes sense to check if there is a new package available.

Comment: The package *wireless-regdb* is the same version in Yakkety as Xenial. :-(

Comment: Do you know what is missing? Maybe OP is on a US router but on an 12-13 channels, or something of that kind. The problem is that it picks the country core from the AP when connects. If that country according to regdb has not this channel, then we get this problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43215/discussion-between-pilot6-and-chili555).

Comment: I think it's working the right way now. I changed router settings to  WPA2-AES and changed the country code (PL). Thank you!

Comment: Hey, today I had some minor issues with connection and I checked what is set with "sudo iw reg get" and it is "00". It stays the same even if I enter "sudo iw reg set PL". I have edited file with "gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda" to "REGDOMAIN=PL" but it stays "00" when I check in terminal. Should I do something about it?

Comment: This solution did **not** work for me.  I mention this because down-voting is not constructive.