# ubuntu16.04 wifi drops every 10 secs. Intel DualBand AC 3160 [8086:847

Tags: networking, 16.04, intel-wireless

Four days ago installed Ubuntu and struggling with this issue since. Tried below from [Unreliable wireless connection with an Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6230](https://askubuntu.com/questions/663315/unreliable-wireless-connection-with-an-intel-centrino-advanced-n-6230/663328#663328)

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"
```

didnt work after reboot so reverted.

tried this too https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214075 and
downloaded the firmware and followed the steps in linked answer but didnt work.

This answer  "askubuntu.com/questions/768843/wifi-problem-on-ubuntu-16-04?noredirect=1&lq=1 "
advises downloading the latest upstream kernel from but I am not sure which package to download.

```
uname -a
Linux A99-Device 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

network info

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 [8086:8470]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

lshw -C network

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 3160
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
   logical name: wlp6s0
   version: 83
   serial: 18:3d:a2:de:ba:d9
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-31-generic firmware=16.242414.0 ip=192.168.1.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
   resources: irq:48 memory:a9100000-a9101fff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: enp7s0
   version: 07
   serial: 20:47:47:53:ab:e1
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:44 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a9000000-a9000fff memory:c0000000-c0003fff
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please let me know if any more info is needed.

Comment: Have you tried these things? http://askubuntu.com/questions/804607/ubuntu-16-04-wifi-intel-7265-slow-disconnecting/804619#804619

Comment: @chili555 I saw this post before but I wasnt sure if it would apply here as the router works with other devices perfectly and secondly I couldnt even figure out how to change the router settings. Can you please give a bit more details. Thanks for your help

Comment: I would love to tell you that every device ever made works perfectly with Ubuntu, Windows and Mac but, alas, it isn't so. To change the router settings, you need to log on to the router's administration pages; something like http://192.168.1.1. Google the brand and model of router and read the pdf manual on line.